# Sorting mac addresses in dictionary?

Tags: python

I am reading ifconig and want to extract interface and mac address. I'd like these to be paired and sorted by mac address in ascending order. I have done this:

```
import re, operator
f = open('ifconfig', 'r')

lis = f.read().split("\n")
interface_dict = {}
for l in lis: 
    l.strip()   
    if "eth" in l and re.search(r'\d\d:\d\d:(\S)', l):
        eth = re.search('(eth.+?)', l)
        mac =  re.search(r'\d\d:\d\d:(\S+)', l)
        if eth and mac:
            eth_num = eth.group(0)
            mac_add = mac.group(0)   
            interface_dict[eth_num] = mac_add

print interface_dict


sorted_interface = sorted(interface_dict.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

However it seems silly to put them in a dict, then I can't sort them as a dict is order-less and I have to put them in a list of tuples. What's the best way to do this, store as a list of tuples originally, sort them and add them to a dict finally?

Comment: Have you considered [collections.namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)?

Comment: what's wrong with keeping the interfaces and the mac addresses in two different list?

Answer (score 0):

Use [zip.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

```
>>> keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> values = [1, 2, 3]
>>> dictionary = dict(zip(keys, values))
>>> print dictionary
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Now, how you should to use it, just implement and adapt it...